# Google Drive docs/sheets/presentation files don't show icons

Tags: nautilus, icons, google-drive

I am using Google Drive for my documents and logged in using Online Accounts in the settings. (Ubuntu 23.10)

It works fine, and I can double-click to open spreadsheets, but all the document files seem to have no icons.

Is there a way for me to add icons for this?

[image: Screenshot of Nautilus showing a Spreadsheet file on GDrive]

Comment: Here are some findings, it appears that Google Drive does not add file-extensions for these files, only mime-types. And adding desktop files with these mime-types does not seem to work, it still does not show icons. Also when browsing these folders in terminal it seems like everything is symlinked so the way Google Drive mounts appears to be some kind of magic to me...